# sorting a query set after a for loop on it

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to apply a method on all of the objects in a query set and then sort them.

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for product in products:
    product.update_exist_flag()

products = products.order_by('-exist_flag')
```

it raises this error:

> AssertionError: Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.

how can I fix it?

Comment: can you add the code of how you create the products object?

Comment: ok, I've added it. @JamesBurgess

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to read: [When QuerySets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).

`for product in products:`: Here, the query `gets evaluated` i.e. data is out of the database. After that, you can not reorder the query.

---

**Ideally, you should do the same query again:**

```
products = Product.objects.all()

for product in products:
    product.update_exist_flag()

products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-exist_flag')
```

---

**However, there is one trick to do it without performing the same query again (without touching the database):**

```
products = Product.objects.all()

for product in products:
    product.update_exist_flag()

# This will return a list.
products = sorted(products, key=lambda p: p.exist_flag, reverse=True)
```

As @heemayl mentioned in the comment, if `exist_flag` is a related object (an entry in a table in the database), then it will hit the database again. In this case still, one optimization is possible, `if` you want to sort based on exist_flag's `id`, then we can use `p.exist_flag_id` instead of `p.exist_flag`, so that, it doesn't hit the database.

Comment: Reversing a very large dataset can be very expensive, so I would not recommend the second method.

Comment: Right! That is why I mentioned `Ideally, you should do the same query again:`.

Comment: If `exist_flag` is a related object, it will hit the DB again (unless you use any prefetching technique e.g. `select_related`).

Answer (score 1):

Perform the query again:

```
products = Product.objects.all()
for product in products:
    product.update_exist_flag()

products = Product.objects.all().order_by('-exist_flag')
```

Generally, any time you want to perform any operation on models, do it in the database level, it would be faster than performing it in on the python level.